# Creating OO CRUD class -query returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, crud

I am trying to make my own CRUD class from scratch with PHP. Connection is fine, but when I try to execute query, it gives me null.

```
        class CRUD {

            private static $link;           // Connection Var
            private $error;                 // Display Mysql error
            private $sql_query;            //   Contains SQL query stings
            private $debug = TRUE;         //TRUE will show SQL queries

            public function __construct() {
                $this->connect();

            }
             private function connect() {
                try {
                    self::$link = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
                    if (self::$link->error) {
                        throw new Exception('Error connecting to DB.');
                    }
                } catch (Exception $exc) {
                    echo $exc->getMessage();
                }
            }
                public function query($sql) {


                try {
                    if (self::$link->query($sql) === FALSE) {

                        throw new Exception("<p style='color:red;'> Query failed. </p> <br> ");
                    }
                } catch (Exception $exc) {
                    echo $exc->getMessage();
                }
            }   
  public static function fetch($res) {
        try {
            return self::$link->fetch_object($res);
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo $exc->getMessage();
        }
    }
     }

    $db = new CRUD();
    $sql = "SELECT * from users";
    $query = $db->query($sql);
```

And it returns null... Query is ok, i don't know what could be a problem.
And when I try to use "fetch()" method it returns me error like this:
***Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_object()***

If someone can take a look and help please, I will apreciate.
thanks